# Probability question involving drawing balls from bags

Tags: probability

Two balls are drawn from a bag containing 10 balls numbered from 0 to 9.   What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the balls is 7? is the answer 4/100 = 2/50

Comment: How many possible pairs are there?  How many of those pairs add to $7$?

Comment: I don't really know. The question I got was given to me as it is?

Comment: These are things you can figure out.  I assume that you are drawing without replacement, yes?  So...how many choices are there for the first ball?  Then for the second?

Comment: Well, count them. See which pairs of balls make up 7 and divide that count by the number of all the balls.

Comment: As to the pairs that add to $7$, you can simply list them.

Comment: for example, there are paisr that make 7 ( 3 and 4, 1 and 6).  should i also include the pairs that is (4 and 3, 6 and 1)

Comment: You can do it either way.  But whichever you decide, you must be consistent.  That is, if you choose ordered pairs at one point you should always work with ordered pairs.

Comment: So the answer is 4/10 which is 2/5, right?

Comment: Am i right on that one. There are 4 possible combinations

Comment: If you are working with unordered combinations you have $\{0,7\},\{1,6\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$ so yes, there are four.  Now how many unordered pairs are possible?

Comment: Four are possible. {0,7 1,6 2,5 and 3,4}, therefore 4/10, right??

Comment: There are more than 10 possible ways to select any two balls from ten.

Comment: so is it 4/40 which is 1/10?

Comment: or is it 4/100?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a $1$ and a $6$... or a $2$ and a $5$... or a ....

Can you finish this line of reasoning?

Comment: Yes I can. should i also include 6 and 1, 2 and 5...?

Comment: But you said you could finish this line of reasoning?!

Comment: sorry, i guess i was wrong

Comment: So is the answer 4/10 or 2/5?

Comment: Am i right on that one. There are 4 possible combinations